# google visualization line chart remove horizontal grid lines

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How do I remove the horizontal grid lines in a Google visualization line chart? I have already tried setting

```
minorGridlines: {count: 0 }, gridlines: {count: 0 }
```

on both hAxis and vAxis.

Here is a jsfiddle of my chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/martlark/2XBhc/

[image]

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Added sensible edit to better explain my tries.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Set the `vAxis.gridlines.color` option to "transparent" to make them disappear:

```
vAxis: {
    gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for the charts when displayed in IE < 9 (as those versions use VML instead of SVG, and the chart's don't support transparency in VML).  In this case, you will need to set the gridline color to match the background color of the chart.

Comment: Still got the middle line!

Comment: On your "fake" y axis, you need to set the "baselineColor" option to transparent as well.  Also, you shouldn't use the vAxis option when using the vAxes option, as the behavior of the interaction between the two is unknown - just set the gridline color in each vAxes axis suboption and you'll be fine.  See both here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/2XBhc/4/.

Comment: And of course of horizontal lines, it would be hAxis

Answer (score 14):

Set gridlines color to none

```
 gridlines: {
                color: 'none'
            }
```

This will also work

Answer (score 1):

Tested & Working...

```
options = {
  vAxis: {
    gridlines: {
      interval: 0
    }      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gridlines.count:0` is mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

> You can specify a value of 1 to only draw one gridline, or 0 to draw no gridlines.