# Google Line Chart - how to remove the grid

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I just started to get into Google Chart to visualize elevation from a google map.

Like here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths?hl=de

Now i got the problem that my chart shows a grid in the background, but i only want get a curved line.

How to disable the Grid in the background?

This is my code:

```
<script>
    // Load the Visualization API and the columnchart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['columnchart']});

    function initMap() {
        // The following path marks a path from Mt. Whitney, the highest point in the
        // continental United States to Badwater, Death Valley, the lowest point.
        var path = [
            {lat: 49.210027, lng: 8.827083},
            {lat: 49.210577, lng: 8.825538},
            {lat: 49.210794, lng: 8.823505}];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: path[1],
            mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        // Create an ElevationService.
        var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;

        // Draw the path, using the Visualization API and the Elevation service.
        displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);
    }

    function displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map) {
        // Display a polyline of the elevation path.
        new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path,
            strokeColor: 'green',
            opacity: 0.4,
            map: map
        });

        // Create a PathElevationRequest object using this array.
        // Ask for 256 samples along that path.
        // Initiate the path request.
        elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
            'path': path,
            'samples': 30
        }, plotElevation);
    }

    // Takes an array of ElevationResult objects, draws the path on the map
    // and plots the elevation profile on a Visualization API ColumnChart.
    function plotElevation(elevations, status) {
        var chartDiv = document.getElementById('elevation_chart');
        if (status !== google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
            // Show the error code inside the chartDiv.
            chartDiv.innerHTML = 'Cannot show elevation: request failed because ' +
                    status;
            return;
        }
        // Create a new chart in the elevation_chart DIV.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);

        // Extract the data from which to populate the chart.
        // Because the samples are equidistant, the 'Sample'
        // column here does double duty as distance along the
        // X axis.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
        for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
            data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
        }

        console.log(data);
        var mysettings = {
            height: 150,
            legend: 'none',
            curveType: 'function',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            axisFontSize: 0,
            hAxis: {
                gridlines: {
                    count: 0,
                    color: 'transparent'
                },
                scaleType: 'log',
                minValue: 0,
                baselineColor: 'transparent'
            },
            vAxis: {
                gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                },
                scaleType: 'log',
                minValue: 0,
                baselineColor: 'transparent'
            }
        };

        // Draw the chart using the data within its DIV.
        chart.draw(data, mysettings);
    }
</script>
```

--EDIT--

Could it be in the DataTable?

this is the code of the grid:

```
<path d="M31.33333333333333,136L34.33333333333333,136L1953,136M31.33333333333333,118L34.33333333333333,118L1953,118M31.33333333333333,100L34.33333333333333,100L1953,100M31.33333333333333,82L34.33333333333333,82L1953,82M31.33333333333333,64L34.33333333333333,64L1953,64M31.33333333333333,46L34.33333333333333,46L1953,46M31.33333333333333,28L34.33333333333333,28L1953,28M31.33333333333333,10L34.33333333333333,10L1953,10" stroke="#000" fill="none"></path>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two small issues with the code, which is why adjusting `gridlines` doesn't work

**first**, you'll want to use the latest library loader
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

the `jsapi` loader referred to is...
`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

**next**, in order to remove the `gridlines`, AND get a *curved* line
you need to use the `corechart` package, instead of `columnchart`

to demonstrate, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wwbvqy2/) using the current chart code, which should closely resemble the problem you see now

(for some reason, the code from the fiddle would not work in a snippet here)

using the adjustments mentioned above, the chart displays correctly,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data.addRow(['', i * 10]);
    }

    var mysettings = {
        height: 150,
        legend: 'none',
        curveType: 'function',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        axisFontSize: 0,
        hAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                count: 0,
                color: 'transparent'
            },
            scaleType: 'log',
            minValue: 0,
            baselineColor: 'transparent'
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
            scaleType: 'log',
            minValue: 0,
            baselineColor: 'transparent'
        }
    };

    chart.draw(data, mysettings);

  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vAxis: {
  gridlines: {
    color: 'transparent'
  }
}
```

or

```
gridlines: {
  color: 'none'
}
```

Check this post:

[google visualization line chart remove horizontal grid lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039646/google-visualization-line-chart-remove-horizontal-grid-lines)