# How to remove vertical line in google bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

How to get rid from vertical line as well top title , i need only bar chart , i am using google-chart lib , to visualize  data ,

```js
            function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Type', 'uk', 'China', {role:'annotation'} ],
                ['', 8478000, 1251478, ''],

            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,
                            1,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn:1, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
                            2,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn:2, type: "string", role: "annotation" }
                        ]);

            var options = {
                height: 100,
                legend: {position:'top', maxLines: 1},
                bar: {groupWidth: '35%' },
                isStacked: 'percent',
                    hAxis: {
                        minValue: 0,
                        ticks: []
                    },
            
                backgroundColor:'#fff',

                };
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `gridLines`  color to `none`?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039646/google-visualization-line-chart-remove-horizontal-grid-lines) refers to horizontal lines but the answers may point you in the right direction?

Comment: And from the [Bar Chart documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart), it looks like you can set the color on `hAxis.gridlines` , so you could set it to transparent ?

Comment: Already , i tried to set gridLines color to none , but still not working .

Comment: i have added baselineColor to aoption and set it to transparent , it worked .

Comment: to remove _titles_, set option --> `legend: 'none'`