# R: Cannot remove x and y-axis gridlines on googleVis LineChart

Tags: r, google-visualization, data-visualization, linechart, googlevis

As the title says it, I'm wondering why I cannot remove gridlines from the chart area on gvisLineChart objects in R. I've had a read through the documentation and tried using the respective commands written there - namely:

```
options = list( 
             hAxis.gridlines = "{color:'transparent', count:0}",
             vAxis.gridlines = "{color:'transparent', count:0}"
          )
```

I also tried implementing the suggested solutions in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039646/google-visualization-line-chart-remove-horizontal-grid-lines), but none of it has worked. Below is a snippet of the code I am using to construct the line chart, as well as an overview of my data & a screenshot of the resulting plot.

Here is my data:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5715 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Date: Date, format: "2022-07-21" "2022-07-20" "2022-07-19" "2022-07-18" ...
$ Open: num  14.4 14 14.2 15.3 13.7 ...
```

Here is the code I am using to build the plot:

```
p <- gvisLineChart(
            df,
            options=list(
                title="SIGA Historic Price Chart",
                legend="bottom",
                lineWidth = 1,
                height = 450,
                width = 900,
                hAxis.gridlines = "{color:'transparent', count:3}",
                vAxis.gridlines = "{color:'transparent', count:3}",
                series = "[{color: '#00D1B2'}]",
                chartArea = "{width:\"85%\",height:\"70%\"}",
                tooltip = "{textStyle: {color: 'black'}, showColorCode: true}"
            )
        )
plot(p)
```

Here is a screenshot of the resulting plot:

[image]

I want to remove these gridlines, the axis ticks and the bold horizontal line that goes through y=0 to give the plot a very minimalistic look. How can I do this with R, granted that I've exhausted the above mentioned suggestions to no avail? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following format, to ensure `hAxis` exists as an object...

```
hAxis = "{gridlines: {color:'transparent', count:0}}",
```

**EDIT**

to remove the lines but keep the labels, remove `count: 0`
to change the color of the baseline (*bold horizontal line going through y = 0*),
use option `baselineColor`

```
hAxis = "{baselineColor: 'transparent', gridlines: {color:'transparent'}}",
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works only partially. It takes away the gridlines, however it also removes labels being displayed on the x-axis. It also does not remove the bold horizontal line going through y = 0. I managed to remedy the issue of the x-axis labels disappearing by setting the color to the gridline to white. But I was not able to get rid of the horizontal line.

Comment: see __EDIT__ above...

Comment: Literally found the baseline option just as you posted this. Thanks a ton, I have it fixed now!